# Materialized view (Kusto): filter out deleted values in view, see only the last non-deleted value

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, materialized-views

I have a table in Azure Data Explorer, where all value records are stored. The records are also stored/marked there if a value is deleted.

[image]

I have created a materialized view so that I can query against this. Now I was working on a materialized view, to ensure that it is already filtered out based on 'Isdeleted' and the latest 'UTCInsertDate'

[image: MAT VIEW]

I just can't get it to work in all scenarios. The green one is what it should have in MaterializedView (all red records should be filtered out from materialized views!).

Here I want to see the last undeleted value for ID = 1250948, (i.e. the green one). The first two values should be ignored, because they were inserted before the "IsDeleted" value.

[image]

In this case, I don't want to see any value for this ID at all, because "IsDeleted" has the most recent UTCInsertDate, so all other values for this "IsDeleted" are no longer valid.

[image]

Is it possible to realize this in a materialized view and how?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
    T
    | join kind=inner (
        T
        | where IsDeleted
        | summarize max_UTCInsertDate = max(UTCInsertDate) by ID
    ) on ID
    | where UTCInsertDate >= max_UTCInsertDate and IsDeleted==false
    | summarize arg_max(UTCInsertDate, *) by ID
```

This query first takes the records with  `IsDeleted=true`  and then takes the latest  `UTCInsertDate`  for each  `ID`   on the filtered rows. The result of this subquery is then joined with the original table on the  `ID`  column. The  `where`  clause after the join operation filters out all records that were inserted before the row with  `IsDeleted=true`  for each  `ID`. It does this by comparing the  `UTCInsertDate`  of each record with the  `max_UTCInsertDate`. (`UTCInsertDate`  of the corresponding  `IsDeleted=true`  record). Finally, the query groups the remaining records by  `ID`  and uses the  `arg_max()`  function to get the latest record for each  `ID`  based on the  `UTCInsertDate`  column.

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSTU+EMBBA7/yKyZ7AdJO2C7uAwYtcuKMXYzYljGsVSlJK/Mj+eIEsurhapj1Mpn3zJk0rNJBDAqUw/SoqdLM0lsoQuBdVh3FrtFQHAlmbYoUGy7homorAXX6bqRa1SYXBuKfRyBo958GBPhgPaOSHBFZjF7Yi8CSqFglMN11OOVszvqYMGI3psD3yF8wXYGaDNz1sdPcfy22svyDe2ODALvZt7HZBHNjg3QK8tcGhfeqdjY0WxKENZtRujk6w83jt5GODI7w0UsGrVGUilUIN7lgfIv/OjvD2jBp/vm8ySM6O266uhZafCLV4389+ddJX3FnFg+IDsnTEPWjUlE+W2WW4SS57glDl2TDJ+GDO71GEPuwv5ASuTv4vq1/H8LQDAAA=)

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work very well. If I change the last value (Value10) to true, I also get the same 'Value10' back. Normally, the query must look at the IsDeleted and then return record after IsDeleted (if available).

Comment: Updated the solution with the extra condition `isDeleted==false`.

Comment: Thanks, demo is working, only a materialized view cannot be contain multiple summerize operators or not?

I'm getting this error: `Materialized views query can only include a single summarize operator over the source table.`

Comment: I expect that I will have to use two materialized views for this. The first contains the IsDeleted values and the second must inner join with them

Comment: views cannot refer only tables. Not other view

Comment: So, this would be not possible with a materialized view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255941/discussion-between-aswin-and-e75).